# How to prevent app to crash when starting intent to open gallery app on device

Tags: android, android-intent

I need some help with this.   In my app the user can open the gallery directly to the folder created by the camera intent that is used in my app.  Now the problem i am facing is that if the app is launched for the first time, there is no folder created yet by the camera intent, so the app will crash when the users selects the gallery. (The intent works once the folder has been created)

What i would like to know is is there a way to tell the user that foler doesn't exist or something to that effect without crashing?

here is my code to launch the gallery:

```
String SCAN_PATH;
File[] allFiles ;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/My Images/");
    allFiles = folder.listFiles();

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.gallerydisplay:
        new SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, allFiles[0]);

        return true;
    default:

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

......

public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        mMs.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: rough idea not the code i can give, check for the folder inside specific directory where your app is creating folder as for the 1st time it won't be found so give user a pop-up (alertDialog) to create the folder in that directory...

Comment: Of course you can tell the user that a folder does not exists. Use a Toast to tell him. And you can prevent your app from crashing using try-catch blocks. Do not use allFiles before you checked if it is null. In case it is null tell the user and return. Use folder.exists() to determine if your folder already exists. And do not continue with further code.

Comment: @greenapps,  Thanks,  but could you provide an example please?

Comment: Please try first. Adapt your code. Then we will comment.

Comment: Thanks,  But what i ended up doing was to create a folder at first launch then copy an image from the asset folder to that folder.  now when launching the gallery it will display the image.